# Prove I know a value v in a set s.t. K = H(v)

Tags: hash, zero-knowledge-proofs, finite-field, commitments

Is it possible to prove that I know a value v in a finite set, such that the hash of the value v is K.

Where v is private and K is public

Comment: Yes, in several ways. Using an RSA accumulator is one approach. You should google for "set memebership in zero knowledge". Different approaches have different pros and cons

Comment: @lovesh In this case, the verifier is given the hash of the value they are trying to prove set membership for and not the actual value. Keeping v private. Assuming the set is big enough that he cannot just hash every value. Just clarifying what I mean, as it seemed to be more than set membership

Comment: @AleksanderRas The other one was specifically regarding Homomorphic commitment schemes, while this is more towards hashing algorithms like SHA256, and or not necessarily Homomorphic. I can close this one if you still believe it is a duplicate.

Comment: @WeCanBeFriends Sorry, i misread, i thought hash of the set. Then for your case you can consider zk-snarks. You can look at [libsnark](https://github.com/scipr-lab/libsnark), a C++ library that let you do proof like given SHA-256(x), prove you know x. Although it has limitations like it requires a trusted setup and the choice of an efficient hash function. My [libsnark playground repo](https://github.com/lovesh/libsnark-playground). There are alternatives to zk-snarks like starks or bulletproofs which avoid this trusted setup but are less efficient.

Comment: @lovesh is there a libbulletproof repo like snarks has? It looks quite interesting

Comment: @WeCanBeFriends [This](https://github.com/dalek-cryptography/bulletproofs) is the fastest one. [This](https://github.com/AdamISZ/bulletproofs-poc) is a good one to learn. I did [this](https://github.com/lovesh/bulletproofs-amcl) but on a pairing friendly curve since some of our company's stuff uses this curve.

Comment: @AleksanderRas If I'm not mistaken, it doesn't really matter that $v$ represents a hash value to the Pedersen Commitment, right? Sorry, bit of a Yoda sentence that was.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yes (as far as I know), the core of the question remains the same.

Comment: @WeCanBeFriends I'll close this question. Don't hesitate to comment here or ask a new question if you're still unsure if it answers your question. Hashes are one way and you've indicated yourself that the input domain is large enough, so I don't see how this is any different than testing for a generic message.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yep, you are right, no problem